# implementing math operation in smarty

Tags: math, smarty

I am trying to calculate total amount in smarty . My HTML codes are below :

```
{foreach name = feach item = k from = $res}
    <p>
    Date : {$k->booking_date}<br />
    Price : {$k->price}
    {* $prc=$k->price, $seats=$k->number_of_seats *}

    Balance :{math equation="x * y" x=$prc y=$seats} <br />
    <span id="paid{$k->booking_id}">
        <input type="button" onclick="makePaid('{$k->booking_id}')" value="PAID" />
    </span>    
    </p>
{/foreach}
```

But it is showing warning message saying `Warning: Smarty error: math: parameter x is empty in C:\..`. Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

`{math equation="x * y" x=$k->price y=$k->number_of_seats}` might work better…

in Smarty3 you'd want to this: `{$k->price * $k->number_of_seats}` (no math!) it's simpler (and faster)

Answer (score 0):

The message says it all. Parameter `x` is `$prc` in your `{math}` expression. And I cannot see where you initialize this `$prc` variable...

I see `$prc` only in:

```
{* $prc=$k->price, $seats=$k->number_of_seats *}
```

That is a comment, `{* text *}` is the syntax for comments in Smarty.